# Android : EditText.getText() returns "" (Empty) String on Android 1.6

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch the EditText value on click of a button.

```
String ETValue = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETID)).getText().toString().trim();
```

Every things works fine on other android versions, but on 1.6 I am getting ""(Empty) String.

Whats going wrong on Android 1.6, how this is happening?

Thanks

Screen Shots:

[image]

[image]

Code Reference :

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView 
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
              android:text="Type you text here"  
              android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textColor="#333333" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:textSize="16dip">
              </TextView>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/ID1">   
                <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/keyword"
                      android:hint="e.g. Text here" 
                      android:textSize="17dip"
                      android:singleLine="true" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_width="250dip"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/btnID"
                      android:textStyle="bold" 
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:background="@drawable/icon"
                      android:gravity="bottom"
                      android:paddingBottom="9dip"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"/>      
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/ID2"
             android:visibility="gone">   
                <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
                      android:id="@+id/keyword"
                      android:hint="e.g. Text here"
                      android:textSize="17dip" 
                      android:singleLine="true" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
            </LinearLayout>      

<Button android:text="Click" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Etext.Java

```
public class EText extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID1)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID2)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String ETValue = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword)).getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(EText.this, ETValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
} }
```

> Even this way doesn't works

```
public class EText extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText ETextt1 = null;
    EditText ETextt2 = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if(Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 7){
            ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID1)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID2)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ETextt1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword1));
        }else{
            ETextt2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword2));
        }

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String ETValue = null;
                if(null == ETextt1){
                    ETValue = ETextt2.getText().toString().trim();
                }else if(null == ETextt2){
                    ETValue = ETextt1.getText().toString().trim();
                }

                Toast.makeText(EText.this, ETValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } }
```

> This Works Perfectly Fine :-)

```
package com.test.et;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EText extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText ETextt1 = null;
    EditText ETextt2 = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if(Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 7){
            ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID1)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID2)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //ETextt = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword1));

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String ETValue = null;
                if(Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 7){
                    ETValue = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword2)).getText().toString().trim();
                }else{
                    ETValue = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword1)).getText().toString().trim();
                }

                Toast.makeText(EText.this, ETValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } }
```

Comment: what does it give you when you don't do trim() ?

Comment: When I debug I can only see "", In Logcat no Exceptions

Comment: You should be using getEditableText instead of getText.

Comment: have you tried doing setText() before you fetch to see if the text value is being stored by EditText?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the problems source. You declareted two EditTexts with the same id. To resolve problem just rename your EditText as keyword1 and keyword2. Then, get text from second EditText.

```
public class EdText extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID1)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ID2)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String ETValue = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword2)).getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(EdText.this, ETValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
} }
```

layout:

`

```
    <TextView 
          android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
          android:text="Type you text here"  
          android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:textColor="#333333" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:textSize="16dip">
          </TextView>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/ID1">   
            <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
                  android:id="@+id/keyword1"
                  android:hint="e.g. Text here" 
                  android:textSize="17dip"
                  android:singleLine="true" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_width="250dip"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnID"
                  android:textStyle="bold" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:background="@drawable/icon"
                  android:gravity="bottom"
                  android:paddingBottom="9dip"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"/>      
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/ID2"
         android:visibility="gone">   
            <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
                  android:id="@+id/keyword2"
                  android:hint="e.g. Text here"
                  android:textSize="17dip" 
                  android:singleLine="true" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: I tried that too.. No relief. Could you please tell have to tried coding it?? Please refer the alternate code I have updated to my question

Comment: Thank you very much Anton.. Keep it up.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished struggling with EditText returning an empty string ("").
The reason was that `setContentView(R.layout.main);` was invoked twice:

```
private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  /// !!!
    editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    // some really long and untrivial initialization stuff

    setContentView(R.layout.main);  /// !!!
}
```

It looks like editText1 and editText2 pointed into the parts of *the previous* incarnation of `R.layout.main`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test example for your case:

```
public class EdText extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // string initialised here will always have initial value and never changes
    final String ETValue = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01)).getText().toString().trim();

    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(EdText.this, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01)).getText().toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
} }
```

Everything works fine for API 4. Maybe your probles connected with the moment when you read the string value. see my comment.

Comment: In the above code in Toast Use 'ETValue' which was assigned before and run on Android 1.6 Emulator you will face the problem. (Note: I have build by app using Android 2.2 library)

Comment: Of course you have problem! Because value of ETValue is initialized at Activity starting, and its value is not changed on Click event.

Comment: Can U elloborate more on ur comment please.. Even If I initialize the ETValue in side Onclick event.. problem is same again..

Comment: You shoul read value from EditText inside onClick method. For example: public void onClick(View arg0) { final String ETValue = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01)).getText().toString().trim(); Toast.makeText(EdText.this, ETValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Hi Anton, Many thanks for your patience and support. Please see my updated code reference above.  Which is actually the cause for the problem. Please suggest if anything is wrong/missing.

Answer (score 0):

public class EditTextDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
Button btnClick;
 String ETValue;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
ETValue = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString().trim();
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
        //assign a default value
        ETValue.equals("Welcome!!");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Value is:"+ETValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("EditTextDemo","-----Value of EditText is:----------"+ETValue);
        }
});
```

}}

You can also give value at runtime.. Also that value can be used for further coding.
Hope this will help!!